# Unable to import tensorflow in jupyter notebook (Linux Mint 19)

Tags: tensorflow, jupyter

I am a beginer in jupyter and tensorflow. I tried to install tensorflow but it doesn't work. I did try several of your advice that has been posted before but nothing seems to work.

```
virtualenv --version

15.1.0

python3 --version

Python 3.6.7

pip3 --version

pip 19.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
```

I tried to pip install tensorflow but it keeps giving me this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     57 
---> 58   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     59   from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import __version__

/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in <module>()
     27             return _mod
---> 28     _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
     29     del swig_import_helper

/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py in swig_import_helper()
     23             try:
---> 24                 _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
     25             finally:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_module(name, file, filename, details)
    242         else:
--> 243             return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
    244     elif type_ == PKG_DIRECTORY:

/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py in load_dynamic(name, path, file)
    342             name=name, loader=loader, origin=path)
--> 343         return _load(spec)
    344 

ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-64156d691fe5> in <module>()
----> 1 import tensorflow as tf

/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py in <module>()
     22 
     23 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import
---> 24 from tensorflow.python import *
     25 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import
     26 

/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py in <module>()
     47 import numpy as np
     48 
---> 49 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     50 
     51 # Protocol buffers

/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>()
     72 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     73 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 74   raise ImportError(msg)
     75 
     76 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/tzions/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

It would be great if someone can tell me how to make it work. I have installed several other things that have been pointed out as necessary and if anything else needs to be installed please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

On import, the code is looking for a libcublas.so.9.0 folder you would have if your CUDA version were 9.0, but if it is an other version, 9.1 for instance, then this folder is not found because the final number is different.

When you install tensorflow-gpu-1.5, it requires CUDA 9.0, so you can fix that installing tensorflow-gpu-1.4 if your CUDA version is 8.0, because it will be the one required, with:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.4
```

If your CUDA version is a later one like CUDA 9.1, you can downgrade CUDA version to 9.0 if you do not need later functionalities, with:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-9.0
```

and stay with tensorflow-gpu-1.5.

Comment: nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Fri_Nov__3_21:07:56_CDT_2017
Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85

Comment: still have this ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You can downgrade CUDA to 9.0 with:

Comment: sudo apt-get install cuda-9.0

Comment: and return to the tensorflow version that works with it with: pip install --upgrade tensorflow-gpu==1.5